# JavaScript to perform a simple calculation on the click of a button and put result in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have some JavaScript activate when I click a button.

The action is for a simple calculation to appear in a text box.

This is what I have got so far, but it's not working currently:

```js
function to_mjd() {

  var number;

  number = 5 + 7;

  document.getElementById("mjd").value = number;

}
```

```html
<input id="mjd" class="textbox2" type="text" name="mjd" placeholder="NNNNN" maxlength="5">

<input type="submit" onclick="to_mjd();" value="CONVERT">
```

Can anyone point where I'm going wrong please?

---

I am editing my original post to add the entirety of the html and the javascript code. Hopefully this will help.

**ENTIRE HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Converter</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" > -->
  </head>

  <body>





    <div class="band1">
      <center>
        <h1>CONVERTER</h1>
      </center>
    </div>

    <div id ="band" class="band2">
      <center>
        <form>
          <span class="span1">
            <span class="date">
              Year:<br><br>
              <input class="textbox1" type="text" name="year" placeholder="yyyy" maxlength="4">
            </span>
            <span class="date">
              Month:<br><br>
              <input class="textbox1" type="text" name="month" placeholder="mm" maxlength="2">
            </span>
            <span class="date">
              Day:<br><br>
              <input class="textbox1" type="text" name="day" placeholder="dd" maxlength="2">
            </span>
          </span>
            <span class="span2">
              <input type="button" onclick="to_mjd();" value="CONVERT">
            </span>
          <span class="span3">
            MJD:<br><br>
            <input id="mjd" class="textbox2" type="text" name="mjd" placeholder="NNNNN" maxlength="5">
          </span>
        </form>
      </center>
    </div>

    <script src="https://rawgit.com/bgrins/TinyColor/master/tinycolor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**ENTIRE JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var color = '#'+('000000' + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)).slice(-6);

    document.getElementById("band").style.background = color;

    var c = tinycolor(color);

    if (c.isDark())
        document.getElementById("band").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
    else
        document.getElementById("band").style.color = "#000000";

    function to_mjd() {

        var number;

        number = 5+7;

        document.getElementById("mjd").value = number;

    }

});
```

Comment: Can you define *not working currently*?

Comment: Nothing appears in the text box when I click the button.

Comment: The input type of submit submits a form, and the page is reloaded as the server response ..?

Comment: i tried copy-pasting whatever you had there (i added script tags though) and it seems to be working.. is it within any other element that might have affected your script?

Comment: You should probably change input type submit with a button, cause as @Teemu said the submit submits a form and refreshes the page unless you prevent it

Comment: I get this error in my console: Uncaught ReferenceError: to_mjd is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick. Does it matter that my link to the script.js file is at the bottom of my HTML document?

Comment: Can you tell, where have you included your script file in your HTML? If its outside body tag then put it inside the body tag.

Comment: My script file is at the bottom but inside the body.

Comment: In that case there's a syntax error somewhere inside the script tag. That error is not included in the post though. Or the function is declared outside of the global scope. Is the script wrapped within script tag?

Comment: Now! `to_mjd` is declared within DOM ready function, it's not global. You've either to move the declaration to the global scope, or rather use event attaching by jQuery.

Comment: `to_mjd` is a local function. button can not find it. When you click that button you will see an error in browser console. Error="Uncaught ReferenceError: to_mjd is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_mjd` is a local function and button can not see it.
Simply change function location in your js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var color = '#'+('000000' + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)).slice(-6);

        document.getElementById("band").style.background = color;

        var c = tinycolor(color);

        if (c.isDark())
            document.getElementById("band").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
        else
            document.getElementById("band").style.color = "#000000";

    });


var to_mjd = function() {

   var number;

   number = 5+7;

   document.getElementById("mjd").value = number;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use `input type='button'` to replace `input type='submit'`

[Check this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vmy9wr4n/)

```js
function to_mjd() {

  var number;

  number = 5 + 7;

  document.getElementById("mjd").value = number;

}
```

```html
<input id="mjd" class="textbox2" type="text" name="mjd" placeholder="NNNNN" maxlength="5">

<input type="button" onclick="to_mjd();" value="CONVERT">
```

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>

     <html>

        <head>
   <title>Converter</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/bgrins/TinyColor/master/tinycolor.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
          $(document).ready(function(){

var color = '#'+('000000' + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)).slice(-6);

document.getElementById("band").style.background = color;

var c = tinycolor(color);

if (c.isDark())
    document.getElementById("band").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
else
    document.getElementById("band").style.color = "#000000";    

      });

   function to_mjd() {

    var number;

    number = 5+7;

    document.getElementById("mjd").value = number;

}
</script>
   </head>

    <body>
<div class="band1">
  <center>
    <h1>CONVERTER</h1>
  </center>
</div>

<div id ="band" class="band2">
  <center>
    <form>
      <span class="span1">
        <span class="date">
          Year:<br><br>
          <input class="textbox1" type="text" name="year" placeholder="yyyy" maxlength="4">
        </span>
        <span class="date">
          Month:<br><br>
          <input class="textbox1" type="text" name="month" placeholder="mm" maxlength="2">
        </span>
        <span class="date">
          Day:<br><br>
          <input class="textbox1" type="text" name="day" placeholder="dd" maxlength="2">
        </span>
      </span>
        <span class="span2">
          <input type="button" onclick="to_mjd();" value="CONVERT">
        </span>
      <span class="span3">
        MJD:<br><br>
        <input id="mjd" class="textbox2" type="text" name="mjd" placeholder="NNNNN" maxlength="5">
      </span>
        </form>
        </center>
     </div>    
   </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Reading the comments, it appeared, that there's also an error message ...

Comment: there is nothing in the console

Comment: I mean that OP has also an error, your code works fine.

Comment: Yes I think that finction should be inside a `<script> </script>`  tag

Comment: try to write `to_mjd()` out side your document.ready function

Comment: Though this alone doesn't fix OP's problem, this is also needed after the main problem has been fixed.

Comment: Add your javascript files in head

Comment: window.to_mjd() = function() {

    var number;

    number = 5+7;

    document.getElementById("mjd").value = number;

Comment: You should still be able to defIne it in your document ready handler if you wish-- you just need to scope it so it's easily available.  They're right about the submit button as well, unless you 'prevent.default()' in it's handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just add 5+7, that code should work, but if you're trying to get the values dynamically, you could go at least a couple routes.  The simplest is:

```
<input type=text onclick="this.value = eval(this.value)" />
```

The first  click will return undefined.  Backspace through that and type 5+7.  Click again.  Returns 12.

You could elaborate on that like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>

<input type=text id=input />
<button type=button onclick='output.value += eval(input.value)+"\n";'> = </button>
<textarea id=output></textarea>

<style>
  body{ width: 99vw; height: 99vh; }
  #input{ width: 90%; }
  #output{ height: 90%;  width: 99%; }
</style>

<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
</script>

</body>
```